# Why is my error catcher running for every created object in a while loop?

Tags: java, loops, error-handling, while-loop, nested-loops

I've written a small Java program that reads data from two external text files. The first text file has a list of customers along with a customer number and a balance. The second text file has a list of transactions for each customer, including the customer number, transaction number, type of transaction (payment or order), items ordered, paid amount, total cost, etc. Each customer has a maximum of 4 transactions in the transaction file.

The program then reads a customers in first, each customer is an object, followed by the transactions and tries to match eatch transaction to the customer. After all of this, the program computes each transaction with the customer balance, then prints each customer, their 4 respective transactions, and a final balance after calculating the transactions. All of this works perfectly!

My issue arises when I want to log an error in the event the program reads in a transaction that does not correspond to a customer in the customers file. In the transactions file, I added some dummy transactions that has an unknown customer number (not in the customer file), and at the moment, when I print the error, it prints out for each transaction that DOES have a corresponding customer in the file, not the transactions that do not. And I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I noticed that the while loop keeps running more than it should, and I'm not sure how to fix it. Perhaps someone here can be able to spot my error clearer than I can.

I should mention that a constraint for this program is to not use arrays, lists, collections, etc. Thats why my program currently has none.

Here is the link to the Git Gist for the program: https://gist.github.com/ogre2/4c3307f62d687915f9e62ba90beb7e00

Any help is sincerely appreciated!

Comment: It's been suggested that I rework the main program from the inside out, reading the transactions file then the customers and matching that way. However, the issue that arises is that the program only reads the first transaction and matches it correctly to the customer then stops reading the remaining transactions.

I tried formatting the original code, reading customers in first then the transactions and matching that way. The first 4 transactions are matched correctly to the customer. But, the program doesn't match the rest of the transactions in the file to the other customers read in.

Answer (score 0):

For **every** line in `customers.txt`, you read through **all** of transactions.txt. So, if there are 200 customers, you read the same file, over and over again, 200 times. Each time, you print 'Unknown customer for transaction #' for every line in the transactions file that doesn't match up.

So, if you have 200 customers, and each customer has 5 entries in the transactions file, then per customer you add 5 entries, and print 'unknown customer' for the remaining 995 entries, for a grand total of 200*995 = 199,000 prints of 'Unknown customer'.

Normally you'd just read all transactions into a list of transactions, but evidently your teaching guide (Be it a book or a person), is an idiot, and thinks it is somehow a useful exercise to try to do this without using any notion of a collection type whatsoever. It's not.

Plan A is to ditch this course or this tutorial and find a better one.

Plan B, which is a distant second, is to completely ignore any line where transaction's customer ID doesn't match customer's ID.

Note that it is **impossible** with this code structure and without ever using a collection, to know if there is a transaction in your transactions.txt that uses an unknown customers.txt.

If you want that, you need to duplicate this code and flip it inside out: You'd have to start, at the top level, with opening transactions.txt, and then for each line in transactions, create a boolean variable set to false, open customers.txt over and over again and scan through. If you find a customer, set the boolean. Once you're done reading through customers, if the boolean is not set: Voila. That was a transaction line with an unknown ID.

Your current code is flipped: It opens customers, and for each line inside that, reads through all of transactions.txt.

This all sounds extremely complicated and cumbersome.

But that's because you can't use lists and such. If you had been able to, it'd have been maybe 4 lines of code total to do all of this. Something along the lines of:

```
Map<Integer, Customer> customers = new HashMap<>();
for (Customer c : readCustomers) customers.put(c.getId(), c);
for (Transaction t : readTransactions) {
    if (!customers.containsKey(t.getCustomerId()) {
       // unknown customer ID found
    }
}
```

2 final tips: Your exception handling is a lose-lose-lose scenario. You should remove it all (no `try`, no `catch`), and add `throws Exception` to your main method.  You should almost always do that to your main methods.

This is less code, easier to read code, any errors will provide far more information (there's a lot more to an exception than just a message), and your code flow is improved (right now if an error occurs you just keep going, meaning, if 1 error occurs, most likely you'll see a ton of scroll with a boatload of errors, most of which are repetitions or completely irrelevant. Once an error occurs that you didn't expect, don't keep going, because obviously your brain was not thinking of any of these scenarios and thus the code is completely unsuitable for running in this state. Throwing an exception *stops* execution. That's a good thing).

Second issue: This is unsafe reading of files, but for a homework exercise this may not matter. Don't call `close()` on resources - use try-with-resources ("java try with resources" as a web search should get you plenty of tutorials). For 'real' code you should definitely use try-with, for homework, well, if the code fails, eh, you're there. But it further highlights that this code certainly wasn't written to be robust enough to be shipped to non-programmer end-users, if that was the intent behind catching exceptions and trying to print only the nice part of it.

Comment: After reworking the code from the inside out, isssue I'm having now is that the program only reads the first transaction in the transactions list corrrectly, then stops reading the remaining transactions, I genuinely cannot see what's causing this, I updated the Git Gist. And I gree, if it wasn't for that ridiculous constraint of not using lists or maps, etc., this would've been a much smoother ride.